# Meteor CLI not working on fresh installation

Tags: macos, meteor, file-permissions, failed-installation

I am new to Meteor and am trying to get started. I have run the `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh` command and it apparently installed fine, but whenever I use a command with `meteor` prepended to it, I get a "Killed" message:

```
➜  ~ curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7786    0  7786    0     0  15678      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 15697
Downloading Meteor distribution
######################################################################## 100.0%

Meteor 1.8.0.2 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
Writing a launcher script to /usr/local/bin/meteor for your convenience.

To get started fast:

  $ meteor create ~/my_cool_app
  $ cd ~/my_cool_app
  $ meteor

Or see the docs at:

  docs.meteor.com

➜  ~ /usr/local/bin/meteor --version
[1]    13302 killed     /usr/local/bin/meteor --version
➜  ~ meteor --version
[1]    13324 killed     meteor --version
➜  ~ cd .meteor 
➜  .meteor ls
meteor           package-metadata packages
➜  .meteor meteor 
[1]    13361 killed     meteor
➜  .meteor meteor --version
[1]    13383 killed     meteor --version
➜  .meteor mrt install
zsh: command not found: mrt
➜  .meteor meteor --help
[1]    13416 killed     meteor --help
➜  .meteor cd ..
```

This is very frustrating. I don't usually post to SO unless I've exhausted my options, and since I am trying to learn Meteor, those options are limited, and I have no idea how to debug this. I have been looking around for a while and no one else seems to be having this problem — just seems to be an issue on Windows, but I am on macOS 10.13.6 with 16 GB of RAM. I saw a post that mentioned having this problem on a DO Droplet and they were out of memory, but that's not my issue, I don't think.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit: Permission settings on the respective directories**

*usr/local/bin*

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 {username} admin 4785 Feb 20 06:48 meteor
```

*~/.meteor*

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 {username} wheel 52B Jan 6 16:51 meteor -> packages/meteor-tool/1.8.0_2/mt-os.osx.x86_64/meteor | drwxr-xr-x 3 {username} wheel 96B Jan 6 16:51 package-metadata | drwxr-xr-x 141 {username} wheel 4.4K Jan 6 16:51 packages | ➜ .meteor meteor create ~/cool-app | [1] 6925 killed meteor create ~/cool-app
```

Comment: So does this also occur, when you create and start a new project via `cd ~ && meteor create apptest && cd apptest && meteor npm install && meteor` ?

Comment: Yes, when I type `meteor create myapp` I get the same error. It doesn’t even make it to the directory creation. Even `meteor —help` doesn’t work.

Comment: That's strange. Is there anything special about your `/usr/local/bin` in terms of permission etc?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 {username}  admin     4785 Feb 20 06:48 meteor` is what I have in my usr/local/bin. Most of the other files in there are sym linked though. I don't know if that's a relevant detail or not. There's also a mix of {username}:admin and root:admin ownership. The permission pattern for most everything in there — that _is_ sym linked — is `lrwxr-xr-x` whereas, the non-sym-linked stuff have the same permissions as meteor (mentioned previously).

Comment: BTW here's the output from your command: 
`➜  ~ meteor create ~/my_cool_app` | 
`[1]    1740 killed     meteor create ~/my_cool_app` | 
`➜  ~ cd ~ && meteor create apptest && cd apptest && meteor npm install && meteor` |
`[1]    1762 killed     meteor create apptest`

Comment: This is beyond my knowIedge. I added tags on file permissions and failed installation to attract more help here.

Comment: For what it's worth, I installed this correctly on an Ubuntu machine. However the permisisons were root:root (even though I installed using my regular user), instead of {username} admin like they are for my mac.

Comment: I can at least check on Monday at my Mac at work  the permission and let you know if they differ from yours.

Comment: Here are the permissions in my .meteor directory.
`lrwxrwxrwx    1 {username}  wheel    52B Jan  6 16:51 meteor -> packages/meteor-tool/1.8.0_2/mt-os.osx.x86_64/meteor` | 
`drwxr-xr-x    3 {username}  wheel    96B Jan  6 16:51 package-metadata` |
`drwxr-xr-x  141 {username}  wheel   4.4K Jan  6 16:51 packages` |
`➜  .meteor meteor create ~/cool-app` | 
`[1]    6925 killed     meteor create ~/cool-app`

Comment: These are my file permissions: `/usr/local/bin/meteor` is `-rwxr-xr-x    1 root    wheel      4785  6 Dez  2016 meteor` and `~/.meteor` is `lrwxr-xr-x    1 {username}  staff     52 29 Jan 14:13 meteor -> packages/meteor-tool/1.8.0_2/mt-os.osx.x86_64/meteor`

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**
I have discovered this is an issue with some cloud-configured software that my work provides called Cylance. It is determining that Meteor is a malicious exploit and killing the process whenever I try to run the command.

**Debgging steps**
To debug why this process was being killed I went to my macOS Console, and ran the command `meteor create ~/myApp`, a process named CylanceSvc then logged a message saying, "Too many groups requested (65). Can cause Performance issues when network directories are involved." Then the next entry was:

```
Process:terminated path:/{user}/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.cty1uc.prsil++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node pid: violation:None occurences:1 SHA:
```

When I opened the Cylance program it mentioned it had happily blocked an exploit. I guess it's time to talk to IT. I hope this helps someone else coming here.